# Empty object when sending data via webContents.send

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to send data from Main.js to Renderer.js in my electron app but as soon as it goes in the preload.js, it's transformed in a empty object.

In main.js :

```
  win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    win.webContents.send('setVideoSources', "test");
  })
```

In prelaod.js :

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('videoEvent', {
  setVideoSources: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on('setVideoSources', (sources) => {
    console.log(sources)
    callback(sources);
  }),
});
```

In renderer.js

```
window.videoEvent.setVideoSources((sources) => {
  console.log(sources)
});
```

Both `console.log` show an empty object and I can't manage to find why I can retrieve my data. (Here it's `"test"` but it's obviously the same when I try to send "real data" as object).

If someone has an idea, let me know !